# What's the difference between Kage Bunshin no Jutsu and Tajuu Kage Bunshin no Jutsu?

Tags: naruto

While the Kage Bunshin no Jutsu seems to be taught, the Tajuu Kage Bunshin no Jutsu is sealed, so nobody can learn the jutsu. Does that mean that there's a difference between these jutsus, aside from the number of Kage Bunshin created?

Or, why was the Tajuu Kage Bunshin no Jutsu sealed away?
If there's no other difference, everybody could use this without reading the sealed scroll.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> While the Kage Bunshin no Jutsu seems to be taught, the Tajuu Kage Bunshin no Jutsu is sealed, so nobody can learn the jutsu.

Weeeeellll... not quite! The Naruto Wikia seems to be a bit off on this bit, since the technique that was sealed away was actually the "regular" Kage Bunshin no Jutsu — the technique that's taught is actually the [Bunshin no Jutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Clone_Technique).

---

> Or why was the Tajū Kage Bunshin no Jutsu sealed away?

The [Kage Bunshin no Jutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_Clone_Technique) is a forbidden jutsu, and that was why it was sealed. Since its "massive version," the [Tajuu Kage Bunshin no Jutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Multiple_Shadow_Clone_Technique), is just a variation of the same technique, it was also sealed away.
It is forbidden because of the danger it present to its user, since it distributes an equal amount of chakra between all the clones that comes directly from him. This could easily drain the total amount of chakra from a user who has less control over it.

---

> Does that mean that there's a difference between these jutsus, aside from the number of Kage Bunshin created?
>   If there's no other difference, everybody could use this without reading the sealed scroll.

As for differences between it and the normal technique, I'd say that the amount of chakra necessary would be its main difference in terms of execution — the more chakra you have, the more clones you can generate.
However, most people won't use the "massive version" of the jutsu simply because of the danger mentioned in the above section — not many shinobi can use such high amounts of chakra and safely maintain the technique steady.
Adding "Tajuu" in front of it is just something that Naruto does every once in a while (note that he sometimes generates huge amounts of clones even without saying "Tajuu") when he intends to generate a massive amount of clones instead of a "regular" one. You can double check this in the very first chapter, where Naruto reads the scroll and never makes mention of the "massive version" of the technique.

Comment: And it isn't known what the 'trick' is?

Comment: I think it was never stated. Neither in anime nor in manga.

Comment: Also, I just checked, and the [hand seal](http://i.imgur.com/njZQ5SN.jpg) is the same for the normal and the Tajuu versions.

Comment: they are the same jutsu, many times naruto used kage bunshin no jutsu to créate a really big mass of clones.
he added the tajuu in situations he would créate that or more amount of clones, its the same technique with the mass attached to it, i find this answer a bit lacking

Comment: Although I see what you mean, @xerido, the plot is pretty clear about only the Tajuu version of the technique being sealed. What do you feel is lacking here?

Comment: @JNat well in the first chapter , i mayby missinterpreted it but, it was the specific kage bunshin technique that was sealed, not the Tajū Kage Bunshin. And even in the very first chapter we see naruto doing  Tajū Kage Bunshin with only doing and saying kage bunshin, so i don't feel that the seal revealed something extra and the real limits to kagebunshins is your chakra reserves, as how kakashi perfectly demonstrates telling he can only create 1 bunshin

Comment: Uh... Something's amiss here, @xerido: I was pretty sure that only the Tajuu version was sealed in the scroll — and the Narutopedia seems to agree with me too. I'll investigate further.

Comment: @JNat,like all user created wikis sometimes info can get scrambled.
First chapter  of anime/manga.
Naruto needs to pass an exam, the requeriment is to make bunshin no jutsu. naruto fails is tricked and steals one of the sealed techniques scrolls. trains it and learns KAGE bunshin no jutsu. Tajuu is simply something he sometimes adds when he creates a massive amount of clones instead of what he tipically creates. The reasons for sealing the technique was:
it distributes all users chakra between clones
The exhaustion that the clone acumulates passes to the user.
enough to criple most ninja

Comment: Yeah, I get all of that, @xerido, and I don't disagree with the technique being pretty much the same, with only the amount of clones generated (and hence the amount of chakra needed) being the difference. I'm not sure if when I wrote this (it was a while ago) I had some bit of info I'm missing now... but what (past) me and you seem to disagree on is with regards to whether the "normal" version of the technique was the one sealed, or if it was the "massive" version of it. Maybe finding a raw manga of the first chapter might be helpful, to see if there's any issue with the translation... :\

Comment: If not, then I'll just edit this accordingly — it isn't much of an edit, and it wouldn't terribly disagree with the current version of the answer anyway. And maybe I just worded it poorly back then, because [this other answer of mine](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/3503/49) points here, and I refer to "the regular version" as a forbidden technique...

Comment: See the above discussion, and the updated answer, @looper ;)

Comment: cc @xerido ^^^^

Comment: @JNat, everybody makes mistakes even myself, I think this answer is way better, as you already added, naruto is very inconsistent with the tajuu prefix. and most of the times it is when he is out of combat preparing for something, but here i can be wrong would need to reread it again

Answer (score 11):

I think you guys are messing up the names of the jutsus, which makes it confusing for others who came to find out the actual difference between the two (like myself).

The jutsu that is often taught in the academy is called Bunshin no Jutsu, aka the move that Naruto sucked at. The one that was in the scroll in the beginning was the Kage Bunshin no Jutsu, invented by the 2nd Hokage. It was sealed away because it takes much more chakra for this jutsu than for regular clones, which don't have tangible bodies like shadow clones do. When Naruto says Tajuu Kage Bunshin no Jutsu, he means to make many copies of himself, this is when you would see up 100+ copies of himself. Tajuu means mass, hence Mass Shadow Clone Jutsu.

This reply might be really late but someone had to clear it up.

Comment: as stated by cat, tajuu kage bunshin no jutsu and  kage bunshin no jutsu are exactly the same technique.

The only difference is what stated cat the number of clones.
As the Anime/manga stated you decide how many clones you do at the momento you use the seals. Naruto simply adds tajuu to reinforce the MASS generation.

the rest of the answers are confunding bunshin no jutsu as the kage bunshin no jutsu. kage bunshin is what always was sealed in the scroll

Answer (score 1):

The technique was considered a kinjutsu because it could potentially kill the user if they made too many shadow clones (the distribution of chakra potentially outstripping the user's capacity). With Naruto, he has ridiculous levels of chakra so it's not dangerous to him. High level ninjas like Kakashi know it and use it to create a handful of shadow clones, but Naruto and his insane level of chakra can create hundreds.

I can see Konohamaru being able to pull off a few shadow clones because he's a Sarutobi and they are a pretty powerful ninja blood line.

Comment: Got a source for this information ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Tajuu kage bunshin as opposed to Kage bunshin  is easier to use for large amounts of clones, rather than the 4-10 clones usually used in combat situations, then again at the start Naruto use Kage bunshin instead of Tajuu kage bunshin to fight Mizuki, so I could be wrong but as I said that's what I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two jutsu is that you gain experience and knowledge from other clones,(when naruto was learning the rasen-shuriken jutsu). Other than that these clones can actually take on a persona and react differently in the same situation, (during the ninja war you can see that each clone acts on its own when naruto distributed them), that is the major difference. The Tajuu was invented for stealth purposes (retrieving data). A ninja could send the clone in to find information and then release the jutsu from a safe distance and retain the knowledge the clone learned. Reasons for it being sealed, my guess is rogue clones that exhausted chakra and couldn't be released.

Comment: tajuu and kage are the same jutsu, they both provide knowledge to the user. tajuu is for mass , mass shadow clone technique it was added by naruto

Answer (score 0):

Kage bunshin no jutsu makes the amount of clones you want with an excess amount of chakra to still use jutsu. While tajuu kage bunshin no jutsu make a massive amount with just enough chakra to hold the clones and can't cast a lot of jutsu